# The following changes cannot be made in additive-only schema mode

Tags: mongodb, realm-mobile-platform

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1NWXd.png)I'm trying to create a Realm Database in my React Native project and Synce Data from Mongo Atlas to Realm and I got this error, I tried to reinstall the app but it still doesn't work

this is my error :
Class 'conversation' has been changed from TopLevelAsymmetric to TopLevel.
If your app is running in development mode, you can delete the realm and restart the app to update your schema.]